# Regarding methods of creating more interesting patterns of plus and minus in a summation.

Tags: summation, summation-method

In a summation notation, we can alternate the sign of each term by multiplying the entire sum (or equally, each term) by negative one to the n, n being the term count.

My question is if there are similar methods to arbitrarily create other repeating patterns, like: - - + + or + - + - - , just as examples. Keeping in mind that the intention is to also keep the integrity of the terms being multiplied, i.e., their absolute value remains the same.

I am aesthetically opposed to solutions which hinge on number theory functions like floor or ceiling, but that may just be due to my own deficiency to integrate them with my algebra skills.

Comment: If you're concerned *strictly* about the sign, you could consider multiplying through by $i^n$ where $i^2 = -1$. Since

$$i = i, i^2 = -1, i^3 = -i, i^4 = 1, i^5 = i, ...$$

you could turn the signs into a "$+ - - +$" pattern. I feel like that's somewhat of a "cheating" solution, though.

Comment: I did mean to say intend that the signs are not the only things I am concerned about. I'll edit the original to make it more clear.

Comment: If you have an arbitrary repeating pattern of period $m$, e.g. $+,+,-,+,-$ with period $5$, then the most generic way to write the summation is over period-$m$ chunks, e.g. $$\sum_{k=0}^{n/5} (+a_{5k} + a_{5k+1} - a_{5k+2} + a_{5k+3} - a_{5k+4}),$$ possibly with some extra terms outside the summation if the number of terms is not a multiple of $m$.